# The union of a set with a set that has the finite intersection property has F.I.P

Tags: general-topology

> Let $I$ be a set and let $C$ be a collection of subsets of $I$ with the finite intersection
> property. Prove that for every $A \subset I$, either $C \cup \{A\}$ or $C \cup \{A^{c}\}$ has the finite intersection property.

I am trying to prove the above statement and I am just not sure where to even start. I know that since C has the finite intersection property that the intersection of any finite subcollection of C is nonempty.
Do i need to look at different cases? If $A \in C$ and $A \notin C$.

If $A \in C$ does that automatically mean $C \cup \{A\}$ has F.I.P. or no?

And if $A \notin C$ does that imply $A^c \in C$ since $A \subset I$?

Answer (score 2):

I’ll use $\mathscr{C}$ instead of $C$ for the family with the finite intersection property.

Yes, if $A\in\mathscr{C}$, then $\mathscr{C}\cup\{A\}=\mathscr{C}$, so it has the finite intersection property. However, $A\notin\mathscr{C}$ does **not** imply that $I\setminus A\in\mathscr{C}$. Suppose, for instance, that $A_n=\{k\in\Bbb N:k\ge n\}$ for each $n\in\Bbb N$, and $\mathscr{C}=\{A_n:n\in\Bbb N\}$; it’s easy to check that $\mathscr{C}$ has the finite intersection property. Let $A=\{2n:n\in\Bbb N\}$, the set of even natural numbers, so that $\Bbb N\setminus A$ is the set of odd natural numbers; then neither $A$ nor $\Bbb N\setminus A$ belongs to $\mathscr{C}$.

HINT: I suggest trying to prove the contrapositive: show that if neither $\{A\}\cup\mathscr{C}$ nor $\{I\setminus A\}\cup\mathscr{C}$ has the finite intersection property, then $\mathscr{C}$ does not have the finite intersection property. Start by noticing that if $\{A\}\cup\mathscr{C}$ does not have the finite intersection property, then there is a finite $\mathscr{C}_0\subseteq\mathscr{C}$ such that $A\cap\bigcap\mathscr{C}_0=\varnothing$. There’s a further hint in the spoiler box if you need it.

> If $A\cap X=\varnothing=B\cap X$, then $$(A\cup B)\cap X=(A\cap X)\cup(B\cap X)=\varnothing\,.$$

Comment: I don't know if I am understanding how the intersection of $A$ with the intersection of $\mathscr{C}_{0}$ is empty helps.. Does that imply $A \cap \mathscr{C}$ is empty?

Comment: Or maybe I am not undersatanding because I don't really understand how if $A \cup \{\mathscr{C}\}$ doesn't have the finite intersection property implies there is a finite subset $\mathscr{C}_0 \subseteq \mathscr{C}$ such that $A \cap \bigcap\mathscr{C}_0$.

Comment: So how can this imply that $\mathscr{C}$ does not have the finite intersection property when you just used the fact that it does?

Comment: @Kim: Sorry; I’ve been away for a day, had forgotten how I’d written the original answer, and was thinking of a slightly different approach. I’ll delete that comment in a moment. The point is that you can do the same thing with $I\setminus A\}$: if $\{I\setminus A\}\cup\mathscr{C}$ does not have the f.i.p. there is a finite $\mathscr{C}_1\subseteq\mathscr{C}$ such that $(I\setminus A)\cap\bigcap\mathscr{C}_1=\varnothing$. Now what does this tell you about $$\big(A\cup(I\setminus A)\big)\cap\bigcap\big(\mathscr{C}_0\cup\mathscr{C}_1\big)\,?$$ And what does that tell you about ...

Comment: ... $\bigcap\big(\mathscr{C}_0\cup\mathscr{C}_1\big)$ and hence about $\mathscr{C}$?

Comment: So this implies that intersection is empty, which implies that the intersection of two subsets of $\mathscr{C}$ is empty and thus $\mathscr{C}$ does not have the finite intersection property?

Comment: @Kim: Yes, exactly.